# finding the value of u of equation 5u^2 = 10u

Tags: linear-algebra, roots

I was solving a question, and while solving that problem I noticed something

---

$5u^2 = 10u$

(solving this)
this can be solved as:

$5 \cdot u \cdot u  = 10 \cdot u$

$u = \dfrac{10u}{5u}$

$u = 2$

so my answer was $2$

but at the same time I solved this like bellow:

$5u^2 = 10u$

$u^2 = \dfrac{10u}{5}$

(under rooting both sides )

$u = \sqrt{\dfrac{10u}{5}}$

Now the value of this $u$ is $2$ and $\sqrt{\dfrac{10u}{5}}$ that is the value of $u$ is different. so can you tell me which value is right

or

which method is correct to find the value of $u$

Comment: In the second method you haven't solved for $u$ at all (or rather you solved it in terms of itself). Your first method ignored the case when $u = 0$, so the proper way to solve it is via factoring as Amzoti as done .

Comment: The solutions to $ \ u \ = \ \sqrt{\frac{10u}{5}} \ = \ \sqrt{2u} \ $ are _still_ either $ \ u = 0 \ $ or $ \ u = 2 \ $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly when you write $u^2 = \dfrac{10u}{5}$ then this will imply $u = \pm\sqrt{\dfrac{10u}{5}}$ and then since $u$ is in the square root it has to be positive. That is why we have to take $u=+\sqrt{\dfrac{10u}{5}}$. You can either check by trial and erorr that for $u=0$ and $u=2$ the equation is true.
Secondly there is nothing wrong with $u = \sqrt{\dfrac{10u}{5}}$, you are just expressing $u$ in terms of itself. For finding the value of $u$ analytically you have to solve the quardratic equation as the answer above mine's has shown.

Answer (score 4):

$$5u^2 - 10 u = 0 \implies 5u(u-2) = 0 \implies u = 0, u = 2$$